# User stay in app when user click in to site in webview

Tags: java, android, webview, web-widget

I have a webview in my android app, but when someone navigates around the site, it opens in a new window, i want it to stay inside the webview.. is there a way to do this easily? Here is the code in my activity:

```
public class WebView1 extends Activity {

    WebView web1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        Intent in=getIntent();
        String urll= in.getStringExtra("url");
        web1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        web1.loadUrl(urll);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach a `WebViewClient` to the `WebView`, where `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` on your `WebViewClient` loads the URL into the `WebView` and returns true.

For example, this activity implements this approach:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2015 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.browser4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class BrowserDemo4 extends Activity {
  WebView browser;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return(true);
      }
    });

    browser.loadUrl("https://commonsware.com");
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WebKit/Browser4))

Comment: my webview is intent url is in mainactivity what i code i need to add

Comment: Intent through load url what to do